# how can i check to see if my sharepoint feature is activated

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I created a simple item adding receiver event.  In there, I just log the information info to log4net file when the event is triggered.  I deployed it in visual studio 2010 and it indicated that the deployment was succeeded.  I uploaded some file, but the log file was not created.  How can i check to see if my solution was deployed and activated using sharepoint central admin?

Answer (score 0):

It won't be in central admin, you'll want to check in the site collection where you're uploading the file from.  In the root of the site collection, there will be a option for site collection features under site settings.  There will also be an option for site features.  If you go to a sub-site, there will only be an option for site features and a link go to the root site collection.

Comment: Thanks, i finally found it, not the most intuitive thing.  if i update my feature in visual studio 2010 and redeploy it, do i need to do an iisreset everytime?  it is sharepoint 2010 server

Comment: If you are deploying from Visual Studio to a local development environment the iisreset is automatic.  You wouldn't need to do it manually after the "deployment succeeded" message.